# iPhone designmode support

Tags: iphone, iframe, safari, ipod-touch, designmode

Anyone knows if Safari on the iPhone and iPod touch supports iFrame in design mode and if so, how I can enable it? I have tried following ways, but none work (but it works on my PC):

```
theIframe.contentWindow.document.body.contentEditable = true;

theIframe.contentWindow.document.designMode = 'on';

theIframe.contentDocument.designMode = "on";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it `contenteditable` instead of `contentEditable`? See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-contenteditable.

Comment: Which Safari Mobile version do you have? It should be working [starting Safari Mobile 10.1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/document/2871122-designmode), which means roughly since iOS 10.1, so roughly since October 2016... that's 8 years after your question. But it's possible that the documentation is incorrect.